VS2022 How do I disable this Design Split toolbar in my html files?
How do I get rid of this? Just seems to have appeared recently in an Angular project and now VS2022 is crashing regularly.
Apparently it's a problem that my post is mostly images, since an image describes the problem perfectly. Isn't 'AI' driven community moderation great!


Tools > Options > Web Forms Designer > General
Select "Legacy Web Forms Designer" and "Start pages in" = Source view
